# how to get image url and send mail before submiting in custom form using wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, email

I am using custom form in my Wordpress theme
here is my form

**HTML**

```
<form accept-charset = "UTF-8" action = "https://forexmplesecondsite.com/get_form_data" method = "POST" target = "_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="customer-name"> your name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="customer-name" name="customer-name" />
    <label for="company-name"> your company name *</label>
    <input type="text" id="company-name" name="company-name" />
    <input type="file" name="customer-logo" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" id="upload-form">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#upload-form").click(function(){
    <?php
    $to = 'mymail@email.com';
    $subject = "my mail subject";
    $message = "please check logo attachment";
    $headers = array(
        ‘From: My Name <myname@example.com>;',
        'BCC: My Other Name <myothername@example.com>;',
    );
    $attachments=$_FILES['customer-logo']['tmp_name'];
    wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers , $attachments );
    ?>
    });
});
```

when someone click on submit, form redirect on other site and i got the mail but i can't see any attachment.

Comment: you are new to php as well as i can see :)

Comment: You need to process the uploaded file ( `move_uploaded_file( $tmpname, $target )` )  and use the `$target` as the attachment

Answer (score 0):

change `$attachments=array($_FILES['customer-logo']['tmp_name']);`, if this doesn't work save the file to a directory and reference that directory+file instead

Edit:
from what i can see you are trying to trigger php on a js click event and that isn't possible, better go with a simple form or a more complex ajax request

Comment: i am trying this function wp_handle_upload(); but i can't understand how its  work and how i actually use in my code

Comment: DID you READ the documentation?

Comment: and how can i save image before submitting  the form

Comment: use ajax with formData to upload the file